# Azure Functions Proxy - route to storage account

Tags: azure, reverse-proxy, azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

I could create an azure function proxy with success  that routes requests to my blob storage. However, it only works if I specify the Backend URL with the full url to the blob file:

ex:

https://account.blob.core.windows.net/site/index.html

where '/site' is my container name and 'index.html' is my blob name.

I had an understanding that I could use the route template as '/site' and if I leave the Backend URL as 'https://account.blob.core.windows.net/site/' what comes after the last '/' would be routed to my storage account. Did I understand wrong?

**UPDATE**
After reading this other question [Azure Function App Proxy to a blob storage account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433813/azure-function-app-proxy-to-a-blob-storage-account) and update the route template / backend url it works, but if my blob name has an extension it does not work (such as .html). Any clues?

Comment: See Hamid's comments [on similar ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433813/azure-function-app-proxy-to-a-blob-storage-account). Fix is expected shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Azure Functions Proxy documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies#a-namemodify-requestsamodifying-backend-requests) they specify how to get the request parameters and pass those to your backend service.

Your template can be `/site/{*restOfPath}`

And your backend would be `https://account.blob.core.windows.net/site/{restOfPath}`

I was able to get this working only on files that do NOT have a file extension. So I was able to add an `index` blob and get to it from `https://myfunction.azurewebsites.net/index`, however, when I tried `index.html`, the proxy returned a message "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: After I post this question, I found another question close to mine. I faced the same problem as you, only works without specifying the extension.

Comment: I leave this question open, so the Azure Functions team can take a look on it and help about the extension.

Comment: We'll route this internally to make sure this is addressed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes we have identified a bug when URL ends with an .extension and will release the fix in the next few days. Thanks much for the feedback.

Comment: The fix is live now.