# Azure Functions - route template with file

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have created an Azure Function that receives an HTTP request and returns an HTTP request.  The function:

1. Accepts an HTTP request
2. Creates a URI to a location in blob storage with a shared access signature that expires in n minutes/hours
3. Returns a 302 status code with the location header set to the URI that will expire in n minutes/hours

I was able to get this to work when I placed the path to the blob in a query parameter, but it fails when that variable is in the route template.

I tried to make the route template: storage/{containerName:alpha}/{path:alpha} but it always returns a 404.  Below is an example cURL of how the request is constructed.

```
GET /api/storage/example-container-name/example.jpg?code=SSBhbSBhIHRlYXBvdCwgZG8geW91IHRoaW5rIEkgd291bGQgcHV0IGEgcGFzc3dvcmQgaGVyZT8= HTTP/1.1
Host: hostdoesnotexist.azurewebsites.net    
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

**Note:The host is not real, path and code are not real.*

I did find this question that was related to the Azure Functions Proxy doing the same thing, but this question is not applicable to the Functions.

[Azure Functions Proxy - route to storage account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449624/azure-functions-proxy-route-to-storage-account)

Using this [Azure Functions HTTP and webhook bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#url) example, and scrolling to the **Customizing the HTTP endpoint** section, I created another function with the following code:

Function.json - id changed from int? to alpha

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ],
      "route": "products/{category:alpha}/{id:alpha}",
      "authLevel": "function"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

run.csx

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, 
                                                    string category, 
                                                    string id,
                                                    TraceWriter log)
{
    if (id == null)
        return  req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, $"All {category} items were requested.");
    else
        return  req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, $"{category} item with id = {id} has been requested.");
}
```

So if the route is products/test/abcd then it responds with:

200 - "test item with id = abc has been requested."

But, if you change this to products/test/abcd.jpg then it responds with:

404 - The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

This is the same behavior I am seeing with the other function I created.

Does anyone know if this is a bug like the proxies example, or should my route look different?  Again, I have this working using query parameters, but it fails when I move the variables into the route template.

Edited - Added files based on feedback
function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ],
      "route": "products/{category:alpha}",
      "authLevel": "function"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

run.csx

```
using System.Net;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, 
                                                    string category, 
                                                    TraceWriter log)
{
    string id = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
        .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "id", true) == 0)
        .Value;


    if (id == null)
        return  req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, $"All {category} items were requested.");
    else
        return  req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, $"{category} item with id = {id} has been requested.");
}
```

proxies.json

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
        "GetJustArtinAroundStorageLinkProxy": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/products/{category:alpha}/{id}",
                "methods": [
                    "GET"
                ]
            },
            "backendUri": "https://<company-name>.azurewebsites.net/api/products/{category:alpha}?id={id}"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is a limitation with the HttpTrigger and it does not support request with extensions (see [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/969) for details).

As stated in the issue, you can use proxies to workaround this limitation, but you do need to remove the `alpha` constraint from your route.

Here's an example proxy configuration that will forward the `id` you have above as a query string:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
        "Test": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "products/{category}/{id}"
            },
            "backendUri": "https://<functionapp>.azurewebsites.net/api/<function>?id={id}"
        }
    }
}
```

You can adjust the above to match your requirements, but this should give you the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working.  It returns a 500 - internal server error.  I made sure to pass the key to the function in both the x-function-key header and also the code query parameter.  Additionally, I noticed that the {category:alpha} does not allow for dashes so something like 'break-pads' returns a 404.  I attempted to turn on logging so that it would push to my blob storage, but that doesn't appear to be working.  My log container remains empty.

Comment: I updated the question based on your feedback with details.

Comment: I've tested with the above configuration and didn't run into problems. Are you able to invoke your function using its direct URL (not going through the proxy)? Can you share an invocation ID, region and approximate time of an error so we can take a look at your logs?

Comment: The issue is with {category:alpha} in the proxy definition. Just use {category}  in the route and backendUri.